# how these array works in Tcl?

Tags: arrays, tcl

I have a question about array in tcl, how the following code works:

```
set Employee_Info_Array(EmployeeId,EmplogeePhoneNumber) "0 12345678 0 0 0"


proc setEmployee_Info_Array {{empId} {phoneNumber} {infoList}} {
    set  Employee_Info_Array($empId,$phoneNumber) $infoList
}

proc getEmployee_Info_Array {{empId} {phoneNumber}} {
    return Employee_Info_Array($empId,$phoneNumber);
}
```

the variable `Employee_Info_Array` is a array, and the initial value is "0 12345678 0 0 0", but when we call the `setEmployee_Info_Array {1,87654321, "1 1 1"}`, how this array is set? are there two entries in this array? like entry 1:"0 12345678 0 0 0" entry 2: "1,87654321,1 1 1"? when we use `getEmployee_Info_Array(1 1),` what we get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a whole lot wrong with the code you have here

```
set Employee_Info_Array(EmployeeId,EmplogeePhoneNumber) "0 12345678 0 0 0"
```

You now have an array with one key/value pair:

```
> parray Employee_Info_Array
Employee_Info_Array(EmployeeId,EmplogeePhoneNumber) = 0 12345678 0 0 0
```

I'm guessing what you really wanted was something like this:

```
set Employee_Info_Array(0,12345678) "0 0 0"
> parray Employee_Info_Array
Employee_Info_Array(0,12345678) = 0 0 0
```

The first command needs a `global` in order to actually use the same array:

```
proc setEmployee_Info_Array {{empId} {phoneNumber} {infoList}} {
   global Employee_Info_Array 
   set  Employee_Info_Array($empId,$phoneNumber) $infoList
}
```

The second command also needs `global`, plus it needs a `$` in order to actually return the value in question. As it was, it returns the the string  `Employee_Info_Array($empId,$phoneNumber)` with `empId` and `phoneNumber` substituted:

```
proc getEmployee_Info_Array {{empId} {phoneNumber}} {
    return Employee_Info_Array($empId,$phoneNumber);
}
getEmployee_Info_Array a b ;# returns literal value "Employee_Info_Array(a,b)"
```

This would be more correct:

```
proc getEmployee_Info_Array {{empId} {phoneNumber}} {
    global Employee_Info_Array ;# same deal, needs global
    return $Employee_Info_Array($empId,$phoneNumber);
}
```

Lastly, the way you list calling it will fail because you're passing in a single value

```
setEmployee_Info_Array {1,87654321, "1 1 1"}
wrong # args: should be "setEmployee_Info_Array empId phoneNumber infoList"
    while executing
"setEmployee_Info_Array {1,87654321, "1 1 1"}"
```

If you actually pass in the values the way you meant to, it works better. Remember, tcl commands are all of the form `command ?arg1? ... ?argn?`. You don't surround the list of arguments with braces, or separate each one with commas:

```
setEmployee_Info_Array  1 87654321  "1 1 1"
```

Putting it all together:

```
set Employee_Info_Array(0,12345678) "0 0 0"
proc setEmployee_Info_Array {{empId} {phoneNumber} {infoList}} {
    global Employee_Info_Array
    set  Employee_Info_Array($empId,$phoneNumber) $infoList
}
proc getEmployee_Info_Array {{empId} {phoneNumber}} {
    global Employee_Info_Array
    return Employee_Info_Array($empId,$phoneNumber);
}
puts "Initial value"
parray Employee_Info_Array
setEmployee_Info_Array 1 87654321  "1 1 1"
puts "After set"
parray Employee_Info_Array
```

Which gives as output:

```
Initial value
Employee_Info_Array(0,12345678) = 0 0 0
After set
Employee_Info_Array(0,12345678) = 0 0 0
Employee_Info_Array(1,87654321) = 1 1 1
```

Comment: Also there's no sense to add more clutter to the proc argument lists by using those {}s when they're not really needed since the arguments do not have default arguments. I mean that `proc getEmployee_Info_Array {empId phoneNumber} { ... }` is visually easier to read.

Comment: You will also need a `global` statement for proc `getEmployee_Info_Array`

Comment: OK,thank you, I am a newbie of tcl, but if we call getEmployee_Info_Array(1,87654321), the tcl can match the paramaters and return the correct result? like  1 1 1?

Comment: Yes, "1,87654321" is just a single array key as far as Tcl is concerned.

Comment: If you're really getting into complex stuff with arrays, consider using SQLite instead. It's more wordy — all that SQL of course — but also more powerful too, and it knows how to correctly persist data to disk, which arrays know nothing about.